# Using taxonomy term in CPT permalink – Pages 404's

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, url-rewriting, 404-error

Having some issues with creating the permalink structure that I'd like. Found a piece of code on Stack Exchange, which unfortunately I cannot locate right now.

I have a CPT called `project` and I want to be able to achieve this structure `https://mysite.tld/taxonomy/title-of-project`

This is working at the moment, using this code

```
/* Initialize Project CPT **/
add_action( 'init', function() {
  $rewrite = array(
    'slug'                  => '%department%',
    'with_front'            => true
  );
  $args = array(
    'label'                 => __( 'Project', 'sage' ),
    'labels'                => $labels,
    'supports'              => array( 'title', 'thumbnail'),
    'hierarchical'          => false,
    'public'                => true,
    'show_ui'               => true,
    'show_in_menu'          => true,
    'menu_position'         => 5,
    'show_in_admin_bar'     => false,
    'show_in_nav_menus'     => true,
    'can_export'            => true,
    'has_archive'           => false,    
    'exclude_from_search'   => false,
    'publicly_queryable'    => true,
    'rewrite'               => $rewrite,
    'capability_type'       => 'post',
    'show_in_rest'          => true,
  );
  register_post_type( 'project', $args );
}, 0);


/* Department Taxonomy **/
add_action( 'init', function () {
    register_taxonomy('department', array('project'), array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'with_front' => false),
    ));
}, 0 );


/* Filter post_type_link to insert the taxonomy term into the permalink **/
add_filter('post_type_link', function ( $post_link, $id = 0 ) {
    $post = get_post($id);  
    if (is_object( $post ) && $post->post_type == 'project' ) {
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'department' );
        if($terms) {
            return str_replace( '%department%' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
        }
    }
    return $post_link;  
}, 1, 3);
```

But, when adding this code, all my pages will 404. If I comment out line 4:
 
`//'slug'                  => '%department%',`

Then it works just fine. I guess it's a permalink collision somehow, but not sure how I'd go about to fix it. Would be super happy if someone could point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up with commenting out line 4 and changing the filter into this:

```
add_filter('post_type_link', function ( $post_link, $post, $id = 0 ) {
    if ( 'project' != $post->post_type || 'publish' != $post->post_status ) {
        return $post_link;
    }

    $post = get_post($id);  
    if (is_object( $post ) && $post->post_type == 'project' ) {
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'department' );
        if($terms) {
            return str_replace( 'project' , $terms[0]->slug , $post_link );
        }
    }
    return $post_link;  
}, 1, 3);
```

Now pages works like they should again. All is well!